# Is there a UNIX/Linux process, which is not associated with executable file

Tags: linux, unix, process, operating-system

In the book "The Design of the UNIX operating system" by Maurice J. Bach, I read that "With few exceptions, every process is associated with an executable file...". I want to know which process does not associate with executable. Is there any answer to this???

Answer (score 1):

You are truncating the sentence which reads:

> every process is associated with an executable file as a result of a prior exec call

`init` or its newer reimplementations are not created from an exec system call but handcrafted by the kernel.

Modern Unix implementations also have kernel threads which are created a specific way.

Answer (score 1):

On linux there are a bunch of processes that are part of the kernel and not specific to executable files.

These are shown inside [ ] in the output of ps.  Technically they are threads but they have their own process ids.

```
root         2     0  0 08:33 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 08:33 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5     2  0 08:33 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         7     2  0 08:33 ?        00:02:09 [rcu_sched]
```